# Display source code with disassembly when path has changed

Tags: gcc, debug-symbols, objdump, dwarf, objcopy

We have some static libraries for a know arch (e.g. powerpc) in which we need to display source code with disassembly to perform some asm review activities.

However, the binaries were cross-compiled in different locations and even in some cases different OSes (Linux and Windows), e.g.
`C:/path-to-mylib/common/src` and others others `/home/user-name/path-to-mylib/common/src`, and so, `objdump -S mylib.a` isn't able to find the source. An option that we have is to replicate the path

I could replicate the compilation path and place the source there. However, I find that method a bit dirty and I guess that won't work from cross platform (between Linux and Windows).

Is there away to tell `objdump -S`  where is the source path located or modify the path with `objcopy`?

Some important assumptions:

- The source code used to produce that exact library is available
- The toolchain for the cross-compilation is GNU compiler and is cross platform (works both in linux and Windows)
- The version of the GNU binutils (GCC, objdump, objcopy, etc) is 4.3.3.
- I am working in linux.
- The object binaries were compiled with debug symbols and information. E.g. `-O0 -g`
- (I don't think this really matters but) I can work with the object binaries extracted from the archive mylib.a
- Re-generating the binaries is not the solution I am searching for.

Let me know if you need more information, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the `--include=` switch of objcopy?

Comment: That doesn't seems to be an option of objcopy.

Comment: Oops, I wrote objcopy, but I meant `objdump` of course.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that option ´objdump´.  In fact, I cannot find in the linux man information about it. The help info only shows something when typing ´objdump --include´. Thanks, that is what I needed.  If you want, you can answer the post and I will mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ssbssa user said, there is an [undocumented](https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/binutils-cvs/2003-08/msg00022.html) `--include=` option (also as `-I`) in objdump.
With this option, you have to place all source code files into a folder and then call
objdump the path to the source code:

```
objdump -I path-to-mylib/common/src -S mylib.a
```

Nevertheless, in this other [page](https://blog.smartere.dk/2012/06/making-objdump-s-find-your-source-code/) they suggest an alternative solution to the problem. By using options `--prefix=”.” --prefix-strip=3` we can replace the prefix of the path when calling objdump. E.g.

```
objdump -S --prefix=”./myfolder” --prefix-strip=3 mylib.a
```

This will allow objdump to search the src as `./myfolder/driver/common/src`, instead of the original  `/home/user/source/driver/common/src`. However, I didn't manage to make it work with different OSes (E.g compiled in Windows, asm+src dump in Linux),